# Copying all files from several folders to 1 folder with a batch

Tags: batch-file, copy

I'm trying to copy several files from several folders into 1 folder with this code:

```
for /R \\wiki\help\images %%f in (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif) do (
    copy %%f "\\10.101.3.21\wikitest\wiki\wikiimages"
)
```

However, it copies all the files as wikiimages, and I can't get around it.  I just want to use the copy command, not an external program (so no `xcopy` or the like).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure

for /R \wiki\help\images %%f in (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif) do copy %%f "\10.101.3.21\wikitest\wiki\wikiimages\"

is the way to fix this, it usually need the \ to know its a folder and not a filename.

Comment: yep im a moron.. i tried to do that but i was getting the "system cant find the specified path", i didnt realice it was calling wikimages instead of wikiimages

Comment: Glad I helped you realise that although I did not find the problem,  cheers.